# 2011 Dynamic CRM Workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have added companies and contacts to 2011 Dynamic CRM online. The contacts are tied back to the company. However, I want to create a workflow that allows me to update the company and add a primary contact to the company record whenever the contact full name is present in the active contact list under the company form. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

1)  A workflow can be triggered by either an event, or by a person hitting "Run Workflow."  It's not clear from your question whether you want this workflow to run automatically or by human intervention ("whenever the contact full name is present in the active contacts list" - that really just means the 2 records are related to each other through the Contact's "Parent Customer" field).  If you want it to run automatically, you would set it to run either on Create of Contact or Update of the Parent Customer field on Contact (or both).  If you want a person to trigger it, you just set it to On-Demand.
2) If you set up this workflow, that means that the newest contact will always overwrite the existing contact in the account form as the "Primary Contact".  This is not always advisable.  You probably want to include a check in the workflow to only run if this field does not contain data, otherwise stop the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow, which triggers on: Create of contact and update of contact.
Then in the workflow check, if the full name is present. If yes you can update the company.